# Al descargar archivos desde aplicacion en VB.NET, los archivos se descargan pesando solo 1 KB cuando en realidad son de 10 MB

Tags: archivo, vb, descarga

Estoy realizando una aplicación en VB.NET en la cual necesito descargar un archivo instalador (.msi) desde una dirección de internet pero tengo el problema que, a pesar que el archivo en la web pesa aproximadamente 10 MB, al descargarlo pesa solo 1 KB, y por supuesto no funciona. Hice la prueba con otros archivos (pdf, txt, zip, etc) y con todos me ocurre lo mismo.

Probé utilizando My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://www.direccionweb.com/Instalador/Setup.msi", "C:\CarpetaInstalador\Setup.msi")
```

y también WebCliente:

```
Dim WC As New WebClient()
WC.DownloadFile("http://www.direccionweb.com/Instalador/Setup.msi", "Setup.msi")
```

Utilizando el siguiente codigo, que abre el navegador, descarga perfecto, pero la idea es que no tenga que interactuar el usuario:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.direccionweb.com/Instalador/Setup.msi")
```

En este ultimo caso funciona tanto con "http" como con "https" pero en los ejemplos de arriba si utilizo "https" me da un error al intentar descargar que dice "Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envío."

Agradecería si me pueden dar una mano para solucionarlo.

Comment: Que pasa si renombras el archivo de 1KB a Setup.txt y ves que contenido devuelve? Porque me da a entender por el tamaño es que el servidor te esta devolviendo un error. Seguramente asociado a no poder acceder via http, cuando quizas requiera https u otro mensaje tipo bad request.

Comment: Me devuelve: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.direccionweb.com/Instalador/Setup.msi">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
Al intentar utilizar https me dice "Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envío.". No se si en este caso se requiere algo mas.

Comment: En un ratito te envio un codigo para que pruebes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta el siguiente código. en caso que veas que requiera HTTPS actualizas la url.

```
        'URL ARCHIVO.
        Dim url As String = "http://www.direccionweb.com/Instalador/Setup.msi"
        'OBJETO HTTPWEBREQUEST.
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        'METODO DE LA PETICION.
        request.Method = "GET"
        'SI SE PERMITE REDIRECCIONAMIENTO.
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        'En caso que quieras usar HTTPS y estes usando NET 3.5 Deberias de descomentar la siguiente linea.
        'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
        'TIME OUT DEL REQUEST.
        request.Timeout = 60000
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        'ACA PUEDE GENERAR UN ERROR EN CASO QUE LA CONEXION CON EL SERVIDOR NO SE REALICE.
        Try
            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.StackTrace.ToString)
            Return
        End Try

        'SI EL SERVIDOR RESPONSE STATUS CODE 200 TENEMOS UNA RESPUESTA.
        If (response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK) Then

            'Obtenemos el stream de la respuesta.
            Dim s As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            'Creamos el archivo abriendo un stream donde se va a guardar el archivo.
            Dim fs As New FileStream("Setup.msi", FileMode.Create)
            'Comenzamos a leer el stream.
            Dim read As Byte() = New Byte(1024 * 4) {}
            Dim count As Integer = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length)
            While count > 0
                fs.Write(read, 0, count)
                count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length)
            End While
            'Cerramos los stream y el response.
            fs.Close()
            s.Close()
            response.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("Error Code: " & response.StatusCode & " - Description: " & response.StatusDescription)
        End If
```

Comment: Si! Ahi funcionó perfecto! Un detalle mas pero ya como un lujo....hay alguna forma de elegir el destino donde se descargará?

Comment: Te referis al destino en el disco donde guardas el archivo?

Comment: Exacto. Poder seleccionar en que directorio se va a guardar, porque esta forma lo guarda en la carpeta donde esta instalado el sistema.

Comment: fijate la linea que dice: Dim fs As New FileStream("Setup.msi", FileMode.Create)
donde dice Setup.msi ahi podes poner la ruta completa que quieras.
por defecto cuando no indicas la ruta es el directorio de la app donde corre.